# How to find values for variable p,q,v for the method "func" when ("Reached to end") is printing only

Tags: java, loops

```
public class Ques {
    static void fail(){
        System.out.println("Nope!");
        System.exit(-1);
        }
    private static void func(long r, long i, long g) {
        if(r - g / 7 + 3 * i / 11 != 0) {
            fail();
        }
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        for(p=-666;p<1;p++){   
        for(q=3281;q>3290;q++){
            for(v=1;v>1620;v++){
                func(p,q,v);
     
                }
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("Reached to end");
    }
}
```

Program is reaching till end but how do i print values for p, q, v where all three loops are terminating? Please help me am stuck.

Comment: You could add a line to `func` that prints the parameter values if the condition is true.  But in this case, your `func` is not being called at all because your first loop condition is never true.  That is, `-1000` is not `< -66000`, so you never enter the first loop.

Comment: what values can i pass to method "func" to make it reach till last "Reached to end" ?@DawoodibnKareem

Comment: The problem isn't the expressions that you're passing to `func`.  The issue is that you're never going into the loop.

Comment: I have converted C program to java.                                                                            
    int main(){
    long p, q, v;
    printf("Enter:");
    fflush(stdout);
    if (scanf("%" SCNd64 " %" SCNd64 " %" SCNd64,&p,&q,&v) != 3)
    fail();
    my_func(p, q, v);
    puts("success");
    }
Why the three numbers for this code is "-666 3289 1617" and able to print the last line? Is there any way other inputs values can be found

Comment: I don't know what you're asking, but I don't think you're paying attention to what I'm telling you.  In your Java program, you are making `p = -1000`, then entering the loop if `p < -66600`.  But because `-1000 > -66600`, you are not entering the loop at all.  You need to fix that.  Then you'll find the numbers that you're looking for.

Comment: I changed the loops in the question, thank you. But i want to print all three values of p,q,v. where condition is satisfied for the given function. Every time am printing it, it directing printing "Reached to end". Please suggest

Comment: OK, I told you in my first comment how to do that.

Comment: private static void func(long r, long i, long g) {
  if(r - g / 7 + 3 * i / 11 != 0) {
   fail();
   System.out.println(r+" "+i+" "+g); //i tried, Its not working

Comment: That line you added needs to go BEFORE the `fail()`, because `fail()` ends the program.

Comment: It still not printing on adding before the fail() also.